# Umbraco IMember AdditionalData

Tags: umbraco, member

I want to store some information for a member in Umbraco using the AdditionalData dictionary field.

First I get the member (this code is located in a SurfaceController):

```
var member = Services.MemberService.GetByUsername("username");
```

Then I add the data

```
member.AdditionalData.Add("SomeDataKey", "SomeData");
```

And save it.

```
Services.MemberService.Save(member);
```

When I fetch the same member again after it has been saved, the member does not contain the AdditionalData anymore.

I don't want to create an extra property to save this data. I want to use it as described in the documentation. (IUmbracoEntity: AdditionalData property)

```
Some entities may expose additional data that other's might not, this custom data will be available in this collection
```

**Q: Am I missing something or could someone point me in the right direction?**

**Q: Is the AdditionalData stored somewhere or is this temporary**

(Umbraco 7.2.4)

Best regards,

Tom

(Umbraco forum: [link](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/64348-Umbraco-IMember-AdditionalData))

Comment: No luck here, facing the same results as you - if you did not post this at umbraco's form (our.umbraco.org), do it, chances of getting an answer to umbraco related issues are higher there.

Comment: Ok, I'll post it on the forums as well :)

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve custom property values for the member you can use:

```
var member = Services.MemberService.GetByUsername("username");

var myPropertyValue = member.GetValue<string>("myPropertyAlias");
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what I'm looking for, sorry. This solution requires to create a property first with an alias.

Comment: Yep my bad. Have you tried member.AdditionalData.TryGetValue()?

Comment: No problem ;) Yes I've also tried that.The field AdditionalData is just empty.